# Pivot a column containing list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, dummy-variable

I have a DataFrame called `dfGenres` with one column `Genres` looking like:

[image]

Code for the DataFrame:

```
dfGenres = pd.DataFrame({'Genres':["[Action, Romance, Mystery, Animal]", "[Bromance, Drama, Mystery]", "[Horror, Monsters, Shounen, Action]"]})
```

Pivot means that I would like to have the same number of rows but in each column every unique element from the lists, filled with 1 if the row contains the genre in the list, 0 otherwise.

I tried something with `get_dummies`:

```
pd.get_dummies(
    dfGenres["Genres"].str.split('[\[,\]]',expand=True).stack()
    )
```

but I get too much rows (I only want one and not a multiIndex):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with [`str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
dfGenres["Genres"].str.strip('[]').str.get_dummies(sep=', ')
```